# How get date from time stamp in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

i m doing json parsing and i getting response for data like

`"date":"1330387200"`

so i can convert this response into date format like "DD/MM/YYYY"?.
Does any body have idea please send me.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: see My post for one line solution;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have solve this issue using this code.

```
private String getDate(long dat) 
     {       
         SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");      
         Date dt=new Date(dat*1000);
         String dtInFormat=sdf.format(dt);

         return dtInFormat;
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a SimpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
```

parse your date string to long:

```
long time=Long.parseLong(timeStamp);
Date dt=new Date(time);

String dtInFormat=sdf.format(dt);
```

Resultant string dtInFormat would be in desired format.

Answer (score 1):

This is one line code:

```
public String getDate(long value)//1330387200
{       
    return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").formatLocal(value);
}
```

Test this one;

Answer (score 1):

```
        Date d = new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy");

        for (int i = 0; i < vTitle.size(); i++)
        {
            String dt = date.elementAt(i).toString().substring(0, 10);
            Date formatter = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse(dt));
            String strCustomDateTime = dateFormat.format(formatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:-

```
var myObj = $.parseJSON('{"date":"1330387200"}'),
myDate = new Date(1000*myObj.date);

alert(myDate.toString());
alert(myDate.toUTCString());
```

Comment: thanx for rplay..i am getting time stamp then i m storing that string. after that i want to convert into GMT formate..